# Does this recursively defined set contain all rational numbers $r\in(0,1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

Let A be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. $\frac{1}{2}\in{A}$ and
2. If $x\in{A}$, then both $\frac{x}{2}\in{A}$ and $\frac{1}{1+x}\in{A}$.

Prove that $A$ contains all rational numbers in the interval $(0, 1)$, that is, if $r\in{(0,1)}$ with $r\in{\mathbb{Q}}$, then $r\in{A}$.

This problem has me stumped. It's easy to prove that if $\frac{2p}{q}\in{A}$ or $\frac{q-p}{p}\in{A}$, then $\frac{p}{q}\in{A}$, with $p<q$ and $p, q\in{\mathbb{N}}$, but I don't know where to take it from there.

Any hints or solutions would be appreciated. Bonus points for finding a costructive proof and for investigating whether picking any other rational other than $\frac{1}{2}$ would have worked.

Comment: Try thinking forwards instead of backwards. Which numbers can you get using a few applications of rule 2?

Comment: @Karl Since posting I have tried the problem with numerical examples and I am able to consistently get back to $\frac{1}{2}$ from almost any rational, but I don't know how to formulate it as a proof. For example starting with $\frac{1}{13}$, applying the first case of the second property backwards a few times, we get to $\frac{8}{13}$ and using the second case backwards we obtain $\frac{5}{8}$. Continuing like this almost always leads back to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Similar: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1516909p9039973

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $p/q$ be a rational number from the $(0,1)$. Let us show how we can get it from $1/2$. We apply the following procedure:

$(1)$ If $p/q$ can be reduced, we reduce it.

$(2)$ If $2p<q$ we multiply $p$ by $2$.

$(3)$ Otherwise we transform $p/q$ into $\frac{q-p}{p}$.

First, let us notice that the resulting number is also a rational number from $(0,1)$. Moreover, the denominator becomes smaller if we apply steps $1$ or $3$, and it doesn’t change if we apply step $2$. We can’t apply step $2$ endlessly though, so denominator will become smaller. And the numerator is smaller than the denominator.

If the denominator is $\geq 3$ than we still can apply one of the steps. Eventually, the denominator will become $2$. It can’t jump over $2$ straight to $1$ due to step $3$ because the numerator $1$ would have been multiplied by $2$. And it can’t get to $1$ due to step $1$ because the numerator is smaller. Since the numerator is smaller than the denominator, it will become $1$ on the same step.

An example: $18/23 \leftarrow 5/18 \leftarrow 10/18 \leftarrow 5/9 \leftarrow 4/5 \leftarrow 1/4 \leftarrow 2/4 \leftarrow 1/2$.

Comment: It's also not so hard to argue that this infinite sequence must be eventually constant, and therefore $p/q = (q-p)/p$ and this implies $p/q=1/2$.